# How can I store an HttpPostedFile in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, file-upload

I trying to implement the demo that is on the www.dropzonejs.com site but i am having trouble doing what it is supposed to. I will be connecting it to a database so i can send a copy of the uploaded file info to the database. Has anyone done a clear tutorial with this in asp.net c#? How can i control what i have so once a file has been dropped in the area i will fire up the method for database connections?

html:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form class="dropzone dz-clickable">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message">
            <span>DRAG & DROP FILES HERE</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried this from another stackoverflow post  but not sure it is doing anything it is not passing into the foreach loop:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];

                int filesSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
                string fileName = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
                string fileExtension = "";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                string savedFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\temp\", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension);
                file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Slaks I posted what i found on a previous post on stackoverflow but i am not sure it is doing anything. I am looking more to how i could control what i do with the file after it has been processed or ready for upload

Comment: So are you actually asking how to save an `HttpPostedFile` to SQL Server?

Comment: @SLaks yes how can i connected the file being uploaded to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

If I am not mistaken, the upload is done, the file saved in temp directory as savedFileName.

[Using dropzone.js in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050965/using-dropzone-js-in-asp-net)

[AngularJs, DropZone.Js, MVC4 - Drag, Drop and Preview pre-Uploaded Image(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668672/angularjs-dropzone-js-mvc4-drag-drop-and-preview-pre-uploaded-images)

The next step is stored in the database. The saved files (in temp directory) to be stored in the SQL database. This is what the articles:

1. If you have MS SQL, then a good option is to [filestream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/): [upload filestream data from aspnet](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10373/sql-server-filestream-how-to-upload-filestream-data-from-aspnet-using-tsql.aspx).
2. Another a good option is to [fileTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13192304/208922).
3. The 3. option is to [Azure blob](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/).

Comment: thanks, i wanted to know about the actual handling process with dropzone. i am having trouble of where could i control a file being uploaded